# How to write an extension for Result Enum

Tags: swift

I have represented the results of my API requests using Result Enum with generic type as follow `Result<T: Resource, Error>`

In some cases I do not want to discuss whether the request has succeed or failed but I still need the returned resource as nullable value.

I tried to write the extension as the code below:

```
extension Result<T, Error> where T: Resource {
    var value: Any? {
        switch self {
            case .success(let resource):
                return resource.value
     
            case .failure:
                return null
        }
    }
}
```

However I got these compiler errors:

> Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Result' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause
>
> Use of undeclared type 'T'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create extension as below,

```
extension Result {
    var value: Any? {
        switch self {
        case .success(let resource):
            return resource

        case .failure:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

As in the `enum` definition, `T` is always `Resource` so you don't need to specify in the extension.

But if `Resource` is some `protocol` and you want to put a constraint on `value` variable in declaration then you can specify that in the extension using `where` clause as below,

```
extension Result where T == someSubTypeOfResource {
    var value: Any? {
        switch self {
        case .success(let resource):
            return resource

        case .failure:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I want the value to be getten from the resource. I will edit the question

Comment: Try to put complete code for `enum` and `Resource`.

Comment: The issue was that I use the built-in Result enum. So I had to write `Success` instead of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Write the type constraint as follows:

```
enum Result<T, Error> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

struct Resource {
    let value: String
}

extension Result where T == Resource {
    var value: Any? {
        switch self {
        case .success(let resource):
            return resource.value

        case .failure:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was that I use the built-in Result enum. So I had to write `Success` instead of `T`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like,

```
enum Result<T> where T: Resource {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error?)
}
```

Create the `enum Result` with `case success` accepting a *generic associated value* of type `Resource` and another `case failure` with `Error?` as its *associated value*.

Since you're using the generic param of type `Resource`, I assume `Resource` is a `protocol` having `value` as one of its properties.

```
protocol Resource {
    var value: String {get set}
}
```

Now, the `extension Result` goes like,

```
extension Result {
    var value: Any? {
        switch self {
        case let .success(resource):
            return resource.value

        case let .failure(error):
            return error
        }
    }
}
```

Now `return error` in `case failure` and `resource.value` for `case success`.

There is no need to specify the *generic parameter* `T` with `where` clause in the `extension` again since you did that already while defining the `enum Result`.

**Usage:**

```
struct R1: Resource {
    var value: String
}

let r1 = R1(value: "R1 is of type Resource")
let result = Result<R1>.success(r1)
print(result.value)
```

Comment: The issue was that I use the built-in Result enum. So I had to write `Success` instead of `T`

Comment: What is built-in Result enum? And write success instead of T means? They are 2 different things.

Comment: The built-in Result.
`Result<Success, Error>`
I use it (not define new enum) as follow:
`Result<T: Response, Error>`

Now the extension is written as follow:
`extension Result where Success: Response { }`

Thank you for your answers, they are correct answers after that, but I had to mark one answer as correct.

Comment: @PGDev, [`this built-in Result type`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result).